# How to connect multiple interfaces within DUT in UVM?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have two interfaces:

```
  virtual intf vif;
  virtual i2c_intf i2c_vif;
```

I need to connect them at my top level.

Currently, I am connecting it like below:

```
module tbench_top;
   
  //creating instance of interface
  intf      i_intf();
  i2c_intf  i_i2c_intf();
  
  //Testcase instance
  test t1(i_intf);  
  
  //DUT instance, interface signals are connected to the DUT ports
  adder DUT (
    .a(i_intf.a),
    .b(i_intf.b),
    .c(i_intf.c),
    .i_scl_in(i_i2c_intf.i_scl_in),
    .o_sda_out(i_i2c_intf.o_sda_out)
   );
  
endmodule
```

When I construct multiple interfaces, I got the error as below:

```
** at environment.sv(18): Multiple constructors declared for class environment - only one allowed.
```

Should it be connected using named mapping, or is it the correct way to do it as above?
How do I check whether they are connected? Could you guide me please?

For your understanding, here is the EDA playground link: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/utw9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error points to line 18 in file `environment.sv`.  In that file, you declared 2 constructor functions (named `new`), which is illegal.  Line 18 is the 2nd attempt to declare the `new` function.

To fix that error, you must only declare a single function named `new`.

You are currently trying to add one interface argument to each of your `new` functions.  You can add both interfaces as arguments to the function.  For example, change:

```
  //constructor
  function new(virtual intf vif);
    //get the interface from test
    this.vif = vif;
  endfunction
  
  //constructor
  function new(virtual i2c_intf i2c_vif);
    this.i2c_intf = i2c_vif;
  endfunction
```

to:

```
  function new(virtual intf vif, virtual i2c_intf i2c_vif);
    //get the interface from test
    this.vif = vif;
    this.i2c_vif = i2c_vif;
  endfunction
```

You would then need to modify how you call the `new` function accordingly.